# Is DefaultListModel over-riding the order of actions in my actionlistener?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, actionlistener

I have a section of my JAVA program where you click a button and the actionListener should go through the following process;

1. Change the text on the button from "Start" to "Standby"
2. Add a label to a panel stating that a process has started
3. Execute a method (that sorts data and returns it via addelement to a defaultListModel JList, and finally
4. Change the text on the button from "Start" to "Complete"

as per below

```
uploadNotamButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        if(e.getSource()==uploadNotamButton)
            uploadNotamButton.setText("STANDBY");
        progressLabel.setText("Process Has Begun, standby...");
        progressLabel.setVisible(true);

        uploadNotams();

        uploadNotamButton.setText("COMPLETE");
    });
```

However, when I press the button, the button text does not change, the label does not show, but the method executes.  Only when the method is complete, does the button text change to "Complete" (never showed "STANDBY") and the label stating "the process has begun, standby" displays (when the process is complete).

Is this a feature of defaultlistmodel that takes priority over everything or my coding inexperience?

Also, the data that gets analysed in the method, is displayed in the JList in one go, and not each element at a time.  If the data was shown in the list as it was analysed, it would at least show that something was happening.  Is this not possible with the defaultListModel?

Many Thanks in advance
PG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a feature of defaultlistmodel that takes priority over everything or my coding inexperience?

This has nothing to do with DefaultListModel and all to do with Swing being single-threaded. Your long running process is being run on the Swing event thread, blocking this thread from doing its necessary actions, including drawing text and images on your GUI and interacting with users.

The solution is to use a background thread such as can be obtained through a SwingWorker, running your long-running code in this background thread, adding a PropertyChangeListener to the worker to be notified when it's done, and then respond to this notification.

For example (code not tested)

```
uploadNotamButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    // if(e.getSource()==uploadNotamButton)
    uploadNotamButton.setText("STANDBY");
    progressLabel.setText("Process Has Begun, standby...");
    progressLabel.setVisible(true);

    // create worker to do background work
    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // this is all done within a background thread
            uploadNotams();  // don't make any Swing calls from within this method
            return null;
        }
    };

    // get notified when the worker is done, and respond to it
    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getNewValue == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                uploadNotamButton.setText("COMPLETE");

                // the code below needs to be surrounded by a try/catch block
                // and you'll need to handle any exceptions that might be caught
                ((SwingWorker) evt.getSource()).get();
            }
        }
    });
    worker.execute();  // run the worker
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly.  I wish the books could have explained it as easily as you did.